# Ruby On Rails: Concatenate String in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, string-concatenation

I am new to RoR. I was trying to find a way over googling to concatenate the string in a loop in Controller.

```
assets = Asset.where({ :current_status => ["active"] }).all
assets.each do |a|
      string = string + ":"+ a.movie_title 
end
```

I want to concatenate attribute "movie_title" as a string that would be colon separated.

but i get error

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
assets = Asset.where({ :current_status => ["active"] }).all
string = ""
if assets.present?
 assets.each do |a|
  string = string + ":"+ a.movie_title 
 end
end
```

Comment: It did not work now i am getting error undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: then check `assets.present?` before loop

Comment: assets are there ( i mean there are two records) but still your answer did not work

Comment: just try print assets in console using `logger.debug assests.to_json`

Answer (score 19):

The easiest way is probably:

```
string = assets.collect(&:movie_title).join(':')
```

`collect(&:movie_title)` is the same as `collect { |asset| asset.movie_title }`, which returns an Array of the movie titles. `join(':')` creates a String with the values from the Array separated by `:`.

Comment: Jakob: it worked fine but i had to write the above code out of the loop. What will be the way to concatenate within the loop?

Comment: Right, the above line is the entire loop. If you for some reason need it inside the loop, do what RVG has suggested and initialize the string before adding to it.

Comment: @neeraj what is the problem you are facing with this code? and why you are strict with loop?

Answer (score 10):

Why not just this:

```
"#{string} : #{a.movie_title}"
```

If they are nil you will get `" : "`

Answer (score 3):

Methods `join` ([docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join)) and `map` ([docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map)) may help you.

Try following:

```
assets = Asset.where(current_status: ["active"]).all
assets.map(&:movie_title).join(':')
```